# Null pointer Exception while retriving data from database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, nullpointerexception

Hi all i am trying to retrive data from a table called contacts but it is giving me a null pointer exception at

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(ContactsDBOpenHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS,allcolumns,null,null,null,null,null);
```

can anybody suggest whats wrong??
i have proper data in the table.

public class ViewAllActivity extends ListActivity {

```
SQLiteOpenHelper dbhelper;
SQLiteDatabase database;
ContactsDataSource contactsDataSource;

public static final String[] allcolumns = {
        ContactsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_SEQUENCE,
        ContactsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME,
        ContactsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_DEPT,
        ContactsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_EMAIL,
        ContactsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_PHONE,
        ContactsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ADDRESS,
        ContactsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ZIPCODE
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    contactsDataSource = new ContactsDataSource(this);
    contactsDataSource.open();
    dbhelper = new ContactsDBOpenHelper(this);
    dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    List<Contact> contacts = viewAllC();
    ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(ViewAllActivity.this,R.layout.list,contacts);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

public List<Contact> viewAllC() {
    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(ContactsDBOpenHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS,allcolumns,null,null,null,null,null);
    Log.i("LOGCAT", "rows returned : " + cursor.getCount());
    Contact contact;
    if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            contact = new Contact();
            contact.setSequence(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_SEQUENCE)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME)));
            contact.setDepartment(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_DEPT)));
            contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_EMAIL)));
            contact.setPhone(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_PHONE)));
            contact.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ADDRESS)));
            contact.setZipCode(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ZIPCODE)));
            contacts.add(contact);
        }
    }
    return contacts;

}
```

}

```html
This is My open helper

public class ContactsDBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public ContactsDBOpenHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
  Log.i(LOGTAG, "Table has been created");
 }

 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
  onCreate(db);
 }



}
```

Comment: can you post your logcat

Comment: Log.i("LOGCAT", "rows returned : " + cursor.getCount());  what out r coming here

Comment: its not going there because there is an exception in the line above it

Comment: did i forgot initializing anything??

Comment: possibly you forgot to set cursor.moveToFirst(); paste it before if condition

Comment: comment code and check what value is come cursor.getCount()

Comment: You cannot initialize `SQLiteDatabase` like this: `new SQLiteDatabase()`, there's no such constructor. Is it some class with same name you created yourself?

Comment: sorry that was by mistake .. i was just trying it...   now u suggest ..

Comment: guys how to instantiate database helper?? and database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to initialize your `database`.

First instantiate your database helper and then call `getWritableDatabase()` on it to obtain a `SQLiteDatabase` you can work with:

```
SQLiteOpenHelper helper = new ContactsDBOpenHelper(this);
database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: how to initialize database and database helper??

Comment: First you need to create a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Comment: how to instantiate database helper??\

Comment: What did you try and where are you stuck? Update the question with actual code, please.